# How can I get the values of parameters in the stack frame in c#

Tags: c#, stack

I want to reach the values of the parameters on the Stack Frames obtained with the Stack Trace class in c#.

Can anyone provide some pointers?

I am doing an experimental coding.
I want to know what and how I went through while coming to the place I found (call level).
But I don't want to make a special mechanism for it. Actually, stac has everything I want.

Comment: Can you explain more about the setup and why you want to achieve this? Showing some (pseudo) code would already help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# reusable function to dump current value of local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929384/c-sharp-reusable-function-to-dump-current-value-of-local-variables) It's not really possible without using the .NET Debugger API, which is rather complex

Comment: I am doing an experimental coding.
I want to know what and how I went through while coming to the place I found (call level).
But I don't want to make a special mechanism for it. Actually, stac has everything I want.