# Get all references and values from stack

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have to get information from current context in runtime. So im interested in getting information about current locals and log it.
Context will be changing dynamically, so i cant store info from exact variables.
I can get info from this.GetType() and get all members values, but sometimes its not enough in my case for tracing floating bug.

How can i get all C# references and values from current stack in runtime and get their types and values( as Locals window in visual studio)?

Comment: maybe you can use intellitrace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn973014.aspx

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552478/c-sharp-how-to-dump-all-variables-current-values-during-runtime)? What are you gonna do when you have all values in runtime? What is your strategy to find the bug?

Comment: Of all the possible ways to diagnose a bug, this approach is the least likely one to succeed.  If the debugger does not help you get closer then at least pepper your code with Debug.Assert() statements.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that help you:

```
MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
MethodBody methodBody = method.GetMethodBody();
IEnumerable<LocalVariableInfo> variableInfos = methodBody.LocalVariables;
```

Comment: Thats great solution! But i have to get variables from full call stack. Your answer helped me a lot

Comment: But i can get method caller and get it localVariables - so, with recursive visiting all call stack i can get all variables.