# Know all objects in application memory at a time

Tags: c#, memory, operating-system

Just for learning purposes I would need an approach to know if there is possible to track somehow all the objects that are in memory at a time during an application is being executed.
I suppose that there is some "table" or whatever in the operative system memory where, every time an object is declared, an entry is created.
So what I need to know is there is such a table for the current application being executed and how to access it.

Comment: What Operation System?

Comment: I mean under Windows, ¿is there any difference how and where to access if it is Windows 7, 10 or even Xp?

Comment: look at this https://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552478/c-sharp-how-to-dump-all-variables-current-values-during-runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the whole process and then examine it with windbg. But windbg needs a lot of experience. If you want to dive deep you should leard to use it.

Or you can use third party apps. We use RedGate ANTS Memory Profiler which is a great tool. There is a 15 trial as you can see here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/